# Extracting element from array in JSON with jq returns "Cannot index array with string"

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file:

```
$ cat ~/tmp/example1.json
[
  {
    "keyProp": 11111111111111,
    "values": [
      "VALUE1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "keyProp": 2222,
    "values": [
      "VALUE2"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to use jq to select values where `keyProp==11111111111111`. Expected output is 'VALUE2'

I have tried but without result:

```
cat ~/tmp/example1.json | jq 'select(.keyProp==11111111111111)'
jq: error (at <stdin>:14): Cannot index array with string "keyProp"
```

Comment: I suppose you mean VALUE2 for keyProp=111...111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select a block you need to use the expression described in the docs:

> [**select(boolean_expression)**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions)
>
> The function select(foo) produces its input unchanged if foo returns
>   true for that input, and produces no output otherwise.
>
> It’s useful for filtering lists: [1,2,3] | map(select(. >= 2)) will
>   give you [2,3].
>
> ```
> jq '.[] | select(.id == "second")'
>  Input  [{"id": "first", "val": 1}, {"id": "second", "val": 2}]
>  Output {"id": "second", "val": 2}
> ```

So in this case you need to say:

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.keyProp==11111111111111)' file
{
  "values": [
    "VALUE1"
  ],
  "keyProp": 11111111111111
}
```

To extract the list in `value`, just say so:

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.keyProp==11111111111111).values' file
[
  "VALUE1"
]
```

You can even extract the first value by using indexes:

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.keyProp==11111111111111).values[0]' file
"VALUE1"
```